# 1995 toyota rear drum. what is the metric srew size to release drum?

Tags: toyota, brakes

1995 Toyota pick up back brakes, what is the metric screw size to release drum?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure what you're asking about in the second part of your question? Are you having technical issues with the site?

Comment: in many cases, the small set screw that is used to hold the drum is also the same screw that can be used to help force the drum off.

Comment: Since I don't have a definitive answer this is a comment M5 or M6 are the  common sizes I've seen. Single bolts are cheap buy one of each.

Comment: on toyotas it’s usually a m8x1.25 use a 30mm long bolt and adjust the shoes down before you try or you’ll break hardware.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what your trying to say is you want to remove the drums to repair the brakes. First your have to remove the wheels. The bolt is 19 mm (millimeter).
What the computer has to do with it makes no sense at all.